# How do I determine sound card type with bash?

Tags: linux, bash

In bash, how do I determine what sound card is installed?  I'm trying to create a plugin for Rhythmbox, and I'd like to test for this in a configuration script.

**Edit:**
On my machine, I needed to use `sudo` to be able to use `lspci` and `lsmod`.  @[Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517522/how-do-i-determine-sound-card-type-with-bash/517549#517549)'s answer using `cat` worked without extra privileges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

Comment: What if ALSA isn't installed?

Comment: Then it won't work. But GStreamer (which Rhythmbox relies upon) is hardly usable without ALSA anyway, and ALSA is default since 2.6

Answer (score 7):

```
lspci | grep -i audio
```

Comment: You upvote another answer if you like it and downvote if you don't, explaining why. That's an etiquette.

Comment: Don't be offended, really. You answer misses some important point, I pointed that out. I'll remove the downvote if it is so important to you.

Answer (score 4):

I image you have a list of known sounds you'll be checking for in your configure script.  So you can use grep and lsmod to check which one is loaded.

`# lsmod | grep -q snd_hda_intel`

`# echo $?`

`0`

`# lsmod | grep -q snd_foo`

`# echo $?`

`1`